# Why do I get weird rotations in exported FBX?

Tags: export

I have a simple, extruded cube model with two bones assigned to it. Now, when I export the model to FBX, the bones get weird rotations. I've checked that the bones have XYZ rotation of (0, 0, 0) in Blender, but for example the root bone has a rotation of (90, -90, 0) and the child bone has a rotation of (-180, 0, 0). The armature has a rotation of (-90, 0, 0) which I kind of expect to be there *(as far as I know it's because of the axis conversion)*.

So, where are these rotations coming from?

Comment: Try applying the rotation of the object using **CTRL-A > Rotation**.

Answer (score 3):

When exporting, different formats have different space formats. Usually it's just a case of the axis getting mixed up.

There's some help [here](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/97119-Z-and-Y-Axis), but generally I'd suggest skipping exports if possible.

Answer (score 3):

I personally have similar problems when importing an FBX into Maya (exported from blender).
In Maya 2009 everything worked fine, but in 2013 and later (possibly before that even) I have to rotate everything by -90 degrees on the Z axis. It might be possible to avoid this using settings in the exporter, but I've had no luck with that.

If it is indeed Maya that you're using, just select everything (including things that look like they're rotated fine) and run:

`rotate -r -os 0 0 -90`

Put that on your shelf if you like, you'll probably be using it a lot.